# Story about a nuclear/biological war between the East and the West that forced everyone undergound

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

This is a short story I read in school in the '70s in an anthology.

People had to wear protective suits, and if these were torn, the person inside would dissolve. The protagonist's suit gets torn and he stops to smoke a cigarette. He then realizes that the nicotine makes you immune and runs off screaming.

Comment: I'm sure I have read this but cannot put my finger on it. As I recall there were a group of people, possibly the last humans alive after a bioweapon got out of control. One by one they succumb, and the last person is left because they have some form of disease or genetic condition that makes them immune to the bioweapon. The last person is driven mad by the trauma and isolation and runs off gibbering.

Comment: I think the last line was something like (referring to the last survivor) "his abnormal body chemistry protected him from the <whatever the bioweapon was called>".